# Selecting the row having the max value for one field, grouping by another field

Tags: sql

I'm new to sql, 
I've one table with 2 columns
`Table1`

```
Form_Name | Form_Version
 abc1     | 0.1
 abc1     | 2.1
 abc1     | 1.1
 pqr      | 0.1
 pqr      | 2.1
 pqr      | 3.1
 pqr      | 4.1
 pqr      | 0.2
 xyz      | 0.1
 xyz      | 2.1
```

But i want output as below

`Form_Name | Form_Version
   abc1    |  2.1
   pqr     |  4.1
   xyz     |  2.1`

I'm interested to get corresponding max value of each unique form_name

Answer will be appriciated

Answer (score 4):

```
select
Form_Name,
max(Form_Version)
from tablename
group by Form_Name
```